# Regex/preg_replace to remove extra line breaks between [font#ABCDEF]$text[/font] BBcode

Tags: php, regex

There is a blog where users can post their messages. They can use a font BB code. The problem - the current script doesn't remove multiple line breaks when text is posted between this font BB code (it works correctly for clear text).

So my idea is to add a preg_replace function so that it removes extra lines from text posted within the font BB code. The font BB code starts with: [font#ABCDEF] and ends with [/font].

For example:

```
[font#FF0000]



This text is in red.

Hello world. How are you?






Good, thanks.


[/font]
```

After preg_replace there should be a maximum of 2 line breaks left (eg. if someone adds 6 line breaks, they should be reduced to 2; if someone adds 1 or 2 line breaks they should be left as they were entered, ie. 1 or 2 respectively), etc.

Here is my current attempt, but it doesn't appear to work even though it should be close the correct solution, I hope:

```
$text=preg_replace("#(\[font[^\]]*?\])[\r\n ]+#i", "\\1", $text);
$text=preg_replace("#[\r\n ]+(\[/font\])#i", "\\1", $text);
$text=preg_replace("#(\[/font\])[\r\n]{2,}#i","\\1\n", $text);
```

(*IDEALLY* it would be best not to leave any line breaks right after the opening [font#ABCDEF] tag and right before the closing [/font] tag because line breaks aren't needed there at all.

Comment: `#\R+#` to match any newline sequence one or more times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this kind of pattern that uses the `\G` anchor. This anchor matches the position after the last match, so it is useful to obtain contiguous results:

```
$pattern = '~
(?:
    \G(?!\A)      # position after the last match
  |              # or
    \[font[^]]*]  # start tag
     (?: \K \R+ (*ACCEPT) )? # if leading newlines,
                             # (*ACCEPT) forces the pattern to succeed immediatly
)
(?> [^\r\n[]* \K \R )*? # lines until:
# (\K removes all on the left from the match result)
(?:
    \R+(?=\[/font]) # the end 
  |                # or
    \R \K \R+       # more than two newlines
)
~xi';

$txt = preg_replace($pattern, '', $txt);
```

There is an other way with `preg_replace_callback`: the pattern find the content between font tags and the callback function removes uneeded newlines:

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback('~\[font[^]]*]\K[^[]+(?=\[/font])~i', function ($m) {
    return preg_replace('~\R\R\K\R+~', '', trim($m[0], "\r\n"));
}, $txt);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will convert 3 or more line breaks to 2:

```
$text=preg_replace("/(\r|\n){3,}/", "\n\n", $text);
```

This will remove all whitespace directly after a [font] tag:

```
$text=preg_replace("/(\[font#.{6}\])(\s)*/", "$1", $text);
```

Try it here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/435951e8dd1039ce8da41d64c501f4bf46c79cc6

Comment: So these two line of codes above should be used to achieve the goal?

Comment: @NonCoder Yes, they should do what you outlined in your question. There was another stupid mistake on my part, but I fixed that now. See the updated answer and the link.

Comment: It works almost perfect -the only thing is that it seems to leave a line break/s right before the closing [/font] - would it be possible not to have any line break left before [/font]? - see: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/06ca7240c363bafa6b9bd2d7c5cda44f9540a21a